# How do I make the sidebar on the second page show up?

Tags: formatting

I am trying to extend the sidebar of this template to the second page but anything I have tried has not worked so far. Any ideas?
Thank you :)
https://www.overleaf.com/articles/anmol-mittals-resume/hckxmvhrcbmh

Comment: The "sidebar" is actually the entire right-hand column, which is similar in structure and content to the left-hand column. Strange setup. I'd imagine a regular 2-column document would provide a cleaner interface than using the obscure `\cvsection[<file>]{<title>}` setup.

Comment: Do you have enough content for two pages? You'll need a separate `page2sidebar.tex` for a second page sidebar; the sidebar doesn't automatically flow to the next page.